# How to install ZendLoader at EasyPHP? I got and error about php5.dll can't be found?

Tags: php

I add code into php.ini

```
[Zend]
zend_extension = C:\EasyPHP\binaries\php\php_runningversion\ext\ZendLoader.dll
zend_loader.enable=1
zend_loader.disable_licensing=0
zend_loader.obfuscation_level_support=3
zend_loader.license_path=

ZendLoader.dll is in C:\EasyPHP\binaries\php\php_runningversion\ext\ZendLoader.dll
```

But I got and error about php5.dll can't be found?
I reinstall many time and try diff ways, but failed.

Many Thanks for any help!
Regards

Specs: 
Windows 7
EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11
- APACHE 2.4.7
- MYSQL 5.6.15
- PHP 5.4.24